# How to randomly sample but keeping position of certain values the same in R

Tags: r, random, sample

I have a species list of names from a phylogeny, I want to randomly change the position of certain species names in the phylogeny while keeping a subset of the species names in their original positions.

for example:

```
#full species list: 
names<- c("a","b","c","d","e","f","g")
```

I want to keep the position of (for example):

```
 const_names<- c("b","c","e")
```

therefore, a desired result would be:

```
"g","b","c","f","e","d","a"
```

I have tried this:

```
i1<-which(names != const_names)

names[i1]<-names[sample(i1)]
```

(I tried to adapt this from a answer on another question keeping the position of NA values)

but, names becomes completely random and has not kept the positions of const_names as well as names has thousands of rows that have NAs that i have to remove before finding it did not keep the positions of the names needed.

Answer (score 2):

```
ifelse(i<-names%in%const_names, names, sample(names[!i]))

[1] "g" "b" "c" "f" "e" "a" "d"
```

Comment: I like this answer, but did you forget the `sample`? :O

Comment: @Edward you are right. Have included that. Sorry

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `!=` you can use `%in%` and negate the result with `!` and use the rest of your method.

```
i <- !(names %in% const_names)
#i <- which(!(names %in% const_names)) #Alternative

replace(names, i, names[sample(i)])
#`[<-`(names, i, sample(names[i])) #Alternative
#[1] "f" "b" "c" "d" "e" "a" "g"

#Or insert in the original vector
names[i] <- names[sample(i)]
#names[i] <- sample(names[i]) #Alternative
```

---

Benchmark

```
names <- c("a","b","c","d","e","f","g")
const_names <- c("b","c","e")

bench::mark(check = FALSE,
Edward = {i1 <- match(const_names, names)
i2 <- setdiff(seq_along(names), i1)
names2 <- names
names2[i2] <- sample(names[i2])
names2},
Edward2 = {i2 <- match(setdiff(names, const_names), names)
names2 <- names
names2[i2] <- sample(names[i2])
names2},
onyambu = ifelse(i<-names%in%const_names, names, sample(names[!i])),
GKi = {i <- which(!(names %in% const_names)); `[<-`(names, i, names[sample(i)])},
GKi2 = {i <- !(names %in% const_names); `[<-`(names, i, names[sample(i)])}
)
#  expression      min  median itr/s…¹ mem_a…² gc/se…³ n_itr  n_gc total…⁴ result
#  <bch:expr> <bch:tm> <bch:t>   <dbl> <bch:b>   <dbl> <int> <dbl> <bch:t> <list>
#1 Edward         24µs  28.9µs  31498.  2.49KB    6.30  9998     2   317ms <NULL>
#2 Edward2      24.6µs  27.9µs  33510.  2.49KB    6.70  9998     2   298ms <NULL>
#3 onyambu        25µs  28.7µs  33504.  2.49KB   10.1   9997     3   298ms <NULL>
#4 GKi          14.6µs  16.6µs  57415.  2.49KB   11.5   9998     2   174ms <NULL>
#5 GKi2         13.1µs  14.3µs  65134.  2.49KB   13.0   9998     2   153ms <NULL>
```

Comment: You can remove `which()` to obtain the logical vector `i`, probably a bit faster

Comment: Thanks! Yes in this case it's a bit faster.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `match` here:

```
i1 <- match(const_names, names)
i1
#[1] 2 3 5

i2 <- setdiff(seq_along(names), i1)
i2
#[1] 1 4 6 7

names2 <- names
names2[i2] <- sample(names[i2])
names2
# [1] "f" "b" "c" "d" "e" "a" "g"
```

Or maybe just:

```
i2 <- match(setdiff(names, const_names), names)
i2
# [1] 1 4 6 7

names2 <- names
names2[i2] <- sample(names[i2])
names2
#[1] "f" "b" "c" "a" "e" "d" "g"
```